# How to position rectangle dynamically with 3 labels when user touch on view in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I make 3 labels using a loop now i want to make a rectangle with all of 3 labels x position , I mean where my label x position finished there should be rectangle appear with a miner border difference. When i click on a view only one rectangle appear with the last label3. How can i got rectangle with other looped labels too.

```
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
UILabel *label[UILabel alloc]init];
//whatever label frame and other properties
}
```

i make a rectangle and in my touches begin method i set rectangle frame relevant to label frame...

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(50,30);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [_lbl.text sizeWithFont:_lbl.font
                                     constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                         lineBreakMode:_lbl.lineBreakMode];
CGRect newFrame = self.lbl.frame;
newFrame.size.width = expectedLabelSize.width;
self.lbl.frame = newFrame;
CGRect newFrame1 = rectangle.frame;
newFrame1.size.width = expectedLabelSize.width;
newFrame1.origin.x = self.lbl.frame.origin.x + self.lbl.frame.size.width;
rectangle.frame = newFrame1;
```

See this image i want the red rectangle with all labels but it shows only with one label which is at last generated in loop [image]

Comment: Do you want to show label selected status by minor border around label ?

Comment: – Surjeet 2 no i want a rectangle concatenated with label on right side of label

Comment: Ok, and you want to show this red rect after each label or only after the selected label ?

Comment: yes after each label

Comment: i want when touch any label the red rectangle should become appear with all labels

Comment: Show your code,  how you are creating label and red rectangle ?

Answer (score 0):

think of using a stackView

e.g.
    //Stack View

```
UIStackView *stackView = [[UIStackView alloc] init];

stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionEqualSpacing;
stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;
stackView.spacing = 10;
```

// then inside your  loop

```
[stackView addArrangedSubview: label];
```